# Define a typealias for the whole project

Tags: swift, type-alias

In which file can I define a typealias that works in the whole project, etc.

```
typealias S = String
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

the `typealias` works the same way as variables.  If you want to be global put it outside the class scope at any file.

Comment: ahh thanks!! :) thought it had something to do with the ProjectName-Swift.h file

Answer (score 0):

`typealias` is use to aliasing the existing Data Types. Its **access scope** is same as a variable, if its declared in side the block like class, struct, protocol etc then its visibility also remains inside that block only. it can not be used outside to declare a new variables of that type.